# MySQL: Multiple SELECT Statements in one Query

Tags: mysql

Im still learning MySQL however I would like to know how to query multiple SELECT statements in one query.

Currently I have two queries, one that displays Order count for 12 months and another for one month. I would like to query both at the same time however receive two different results.

I have tried using `UNION` with my query however it only outputs into one table and its quite hard to differentiate the result with what query.

SQL:

```sql
SELECT OrderDate, OrderItems, COUNT(*) AS Total FROM tb_orders WHERE OrderDate > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH) GROUP BY OrderItems ORDER BY Total DESC LIMIT 10

SELECT OrderDate, OrderItems, COUNT(*) AS Total FROM tb_orders WHERE OrderDate > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) GROUP BY OrderItems ORDER BY Total DESC LIMIT 10;
```

TIA

Comment: @Strawberry thanks however that doesn't really work in my case

Comment: If i understand correctly you want two tables with a query. However this is not how mysql works you can only get a table of result not seperate tables. However you can use sub query or union or join to get desired result and seperate with alias

Comment: You don't need UNION, you can get 2 result sets from one query.
Why do you assume they are not running at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge the 2 queries by creating an identifier on the fly whether the record is from the monthly or yearly query. Column `type` is a column for this purpose in below query,

```
SELECT z.*
FROM
(
  SELECT OrderDate, OrderItems, COUNT(*) AS Total, 'YEAR' as type
  FROM tb_orders
  WHERE OrderDate > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)
  GROUP BY OrderItems
  LIMIT 10
  UNION
  SELECT OrderDate, OrderItems, COUNT(*) AS Total, 'MONTH' as type
  FROM tb_orders
  WHERE OrderDate > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
  GROUP BY OrderItems
  LIMIT 10
) AS z
ORDER BY z.Total DESC;
```

[Working Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b861268/11)

Comment: Unfortunately I get the following error:


Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION   SELECT id, OrderDate, OrderItems, COUNT(*) AS Total, 'MONTH' as type   F' at line 9 0.00040 sec

Comment: It's working for me. I have added a fiddle link too for your reference. Check that out.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. So weird that im getting errors...

Answer (score 0):

With union, you can always add hard-coded values to help differentiate rows:

```
select 'Invertebrate' as AnimalPhylum, species as AnimalSpecies from invertebrates_table
union
select 'Vertebrate', species from vertebrates_table;
```

Comment: Thanks however with UNION, I am unable to do ```GROUP BY OrderItems ORDER BY Total DESC LIMIT 5``` after the first SELECT Statement